# Accessing sql server temporary table from asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, sql-server-2008-r2

What I am missing to get data from temporary table. This is showing error like Invalid object name #emp. Please help me
I am using Asp.net.

```
 Dim sqlcmd = New SqlCommand("select * into #emp from employees", conn)
 sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

 sqlcmd = New SqlCommand("select * from  #emp", conn)
 Dim dr As SqlDataReader = sqlcmd.ExecuteReader
```

See Above query is working fine and data is going into temporary table. but it is not selecting again through second one query.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use Global Temporary table instead of Local Temporary tabel like.. ##emp

or

You can just use a stored procedure which has all the SQL statement you want to execute and return your desired recordset.